# How to use maven-security-versions plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Does anyone know the **maven-security-versions** plugin and how to use it? The github page https://github.com/h3xstream/maven-security-versions does not contain much docs?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this in a general sense of "how do I figure out how to use a Maven plugin that is not well documented," because many a time I've had to read plugin code to understand how something works.  Sometimes the documentation isn't clear unless one is a Maven expert.

What you need to know in order to use a Maven plugin is:

- Reporting or build plugin?
- What's the goal name?
- What phase should the goal be bound to?

We have access to the source code, so we drill down into `src/main/java` and poke around at the classes until we find one (or more) that extends `AbstractMojo`.

For this plugin, that class is [SecurityVersionsCheck](https://github.com/h3xstream/maven-security-versions/blob/master/src/main/java/com/h3xstream/maven/SecurityVersionsCheck.java).  It extends `AbstractMojo` and does not implement `MavenReport` so it's a build plugin.  There is typically an annotation at the top of the class (sometimes in comments) that tell you the name of the goal, which in this case is `check`.  Next step is to look at the properties of the class; any annotated with `@parameter` (again, may be in comments) are mojo parameters.

```
/**
 * @goal check
 * @requiresProject true
 * @requiresDirectInvocation false
 * @aggregator true
 */
public class SecurityVersionsCheck extends AbstractMojo {
....
  /**
   * @parameter property="sec.updateRepo" defaultValue="false"
   */
  private Boolean updateRepository = Boolean.FALSE;
  ....
```

With this information, the plugin config would look something like the below.  I picked an arbitrary but reasonable phase for the example.  Adjust if needed.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.h3xstream.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-security-versions</artifactId>
      <version><latestPluginVersion></version>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

This should be enough to get you started; read the rest of the source code in more detail to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to user944849 for his detailed explainations on how to figure out how a maven plugin works. So I was able to make it work:

1. Download the github project and build/install the plugin into the Maven Repository
2. Add the following in the project's pom in the  section:

   ```
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>com.h3xstream.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>security-versions</artifactId>
                   <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <phase>process-resources</phase>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>check</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
   ```